# Has anyone a guide on how to use sky broadband with their own router?

Tags: adsl, broadband, adsl-router

I'm aware its against the T's&C's for sky but interested if anyone has  managed to configure another router other than the sky supplied one and if so how?

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Can't you just plug the new router in of sky's LAN slots, and use the new router as if it were the only router?

Comment: No, the purpose is to remove the sky router from the equation, if you were to do what you have suggested then the sky router would still be the one with the ADSL connection except you'd be connecting to a different wireless access point. BTW, don't try what you suggested, it'd result in conflicting DHCP servers and is unlikely to achieve anything good as a result.

Comment: Nothing so disastrous would happen ccame. The reason is that the sky router would only see the new router, and it would give an IP address to that. The new router instead would IP addresses to anything downwind. You would only have to make sure that the two subnets are distinct. As for the sky router, like all routers provided by ISPs, it is difficult to get around them because you cannot easily find all specs necessary for the connection.